# Specflow and generating the steps

Tags: specflow

I am trying to get hold of BDD using Specflow. One of the problems with Specflow is generating the steps. If I do not have step file then it will generate the steps in output window which I can add in the custom step file. But what happens if I edit the feature file? How can I re create the steps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you already have a step file, SpecFlow will detect lines in the feature file that do not have a matching step definition and will output generated code for those steps. And if you e.g. add a new scenario that uses only existing step definitions, you shouldn't need to touch the step file at all.

Comment: Thanks yeah I just noticed that!